# 'Use of unresolved identifier FIRStorage' (Swift - Xcode 7.3.1)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I've been using Firebase SDK for some months but never got an issue. This time I can't get the storage to work even if I did all the steps correctly. I have the correct podfile and when I do the install I can see it downloads the correct framework and I can see the framework listed in my project, too.

[image: Here is an image of the framework listed.]

I tried to change 'import Firebase' to 'import FirebaseStorage', it recognizes the framework and doesn't give any error on the import, but I still get the same error.

[image: Here is an image of the firebase import error.]

Edit: I know how to show images in my question but I can't do it because I must have at least 10 reputations.

Edit 2: I resolved and I'm waiting to accept my own answer.

Comment: Can you show your podfile? Sometimes Xcode trips, I recommend restarting, doing a clean, and then a build.

Comment: @DavidEast I'm sorry I can't add more images to my question so here is an external link to show my podfile: [podfile](http://imgur.com/a/Df7gj)

Comment: You don't need an image, you can just include it as a code sample.

Comment: @DavidEast thanks for the help but I resolved by creating a new Xcode project with a different name but the same podfile. Thanks for the clarifications, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that project was not working so I created a new project with the same podfile and all went well. Maybe it was a naming conflict because stupidly I named my first project FirebaseStorage.